# how can i retrieve data from database and put in javascript code to process with maps api?

Tags: javascript, php, database

hey i have latitude and longtitude data that i put in database
can i get that data and put it in javascript code to process with map api?

here is my javascript code that i want to change the "latitude and longtitude" in database

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jsMaps.loader(function (){
    var tiles = new jsMaps.Native.Tiles();
    var map = jsMaps.api.init(
            '#map',
            'native',
            {
                center: {
                    latitude: (change data from database),
                    longitude: (change data from database)
                },
                zoom: 14,
                mouse_scroll: true,
                zoom_control: true,
                map_type: true
            },tiles
    );

    var polyLine1 = [
        {lat: (change data from database),lng:  (change data from database)},    
        {lat: (change data from database),lng:  (change data from database)},   
        {lat: (change data from database),lng:  (change data from database)},     
        {lat: (change data from database),lng:  (change data from database)}    
    ];
```

Comment: `can i get that data and put it in javascript code to process with map api`...yes you can. Where are you stuck?

Comment: i don't know how to do it? im new and noob in javascript

Comment: Depends on the structure of your application and where this code is located. You could fetch it with AJAX. Or if this code is within a PHP page you could have PHP simply echo the data into the script so it becomes a hard coded value in the JavaScript. Also depends if it needs to update dynamically while the page is running. You didn't give us much context. But these are all standard ways to include data from PHP to JavaScript and aren't too hard to research. The fact it happens to be latitude / longitude data isn't really relevant, the options and processes are basically the same for any data

Comment: thankyou so much for your enlightment, i will try to echo the data into the script.
but how to do it if i want the javascript update dinamically as much as the location stored in database?

Comment: sir i already try echo the data into the script but failed, the map is not load at all,
this code is in php

Comment: If you tried something please show your attempt, and then we can help you fix it. That's how this site works. Please edit your question to include the code you tried and the error / problem which occurred.

Comment: pardon me sir this is my first time, i will try to include code i already try

Comment: i try too change this line {lat: (change data from database),lng:  (change data from database)},
to this 
 {lat: $row["latitude"],lng: $row["longtitude"]},
but still no result

Comment: If you're going to use PHP code within the block then you need to enclose it within php tags and make sure you echo the values, e.g. `{lat: <?php echo $row["latitude"]; ?> ,lng: <?php echo $row["longtitude"] ?> }`. Try that. Check for errors in your browser's console if there's still an issue.

Comment: i try add your code but the map is gone and i get error in console :
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' on line 53
but there is only this symbol ); on line 53 
and line 53 is part of var map = jsMaps.api.init(
            '#map',
            'native',
            {
                center: {
                    latitude: (change data from database),
                    longitude: (change data from database)
                },
                zoom: 14,
                mouse_scroll: true,
                zoom_control: true,
                map_type: true
            }

Comment: i try to make json, and json grab data from database and it works, but when i try to add the json data to javascript i failed. when i try add console.log(data.latitude) on javascript, the console sayd undefined. but when i try console.log(data) the console show array of latitude and longtitude data

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' `...it must be because this code isn't in a `.php` file

Comment: For the JSON attempt you need to update the question with a proper example in context. We can't tell the problem just from one isolated line of code. Provide a [mre] in the question itself please (not in the comments). Thanks

Comment: hey sorry for late reply, i already solved it watch tutosial on yutub hehe, so i use async function to retrive json data and parse it so i can use it in javascript

Comment: thankyou so much for your help :)

Comment: If you solved it that's great, please put the answer below so that others with a similar problem can benefit - and you can gain reputation points from the upvotes. You're allowed to answer your own question! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i made json file to grab data that i need to process to javascript. Then i use async funtion to extract json file and obtain latitude and longtitude from database.
here is my javascript code to extract the json file :

```
const api_url = 'jsonlatest.php'
        async function getjsonlatest() {
            const response = await fetch(api_url);
            const data = await response.json();
            let i = 0;
            while (i<10) {
                i++;
                array = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data[i]))
                sip = [array.latitude, array.longtitude]
                oke = [sip]
                
                console.log(oke)
                                   
            }
        
                


    }
```

Comment: No you can't just write "I solved it" and just a vague description - that's not much use to anyone. Provide a working example with the code you used and you'll get far more votes :-)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: okey Mr. ADyson i'm so sorry , i will try to follow your Advise :-)